# Can't resolve Domain redirect with xn-- Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

We had a redirect from the domain muehleacker.ch to xn--mhleacker-q9a.ch in the AWS route53. The redirect was made with AWS S3 buckets. Now we wanted to turn the redirection around, so that xn--mhleacker-q9a.ch points to muehleacker.ch. For that, we deleted the old S3 buckets and created new ones. If we know want to access muehleacker.ch in a browser, the page takes way to long to load and displayes an: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error with the resolved domain mühleacker.ch (xn--mhleacker-q9a.ch) in the addressbar.

Any Idea what we are missing?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: "Bucket names can't begin with xn-- (for buckets created after February 2020)." See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could fix the problem by our self. There wasn't a problem with the AWS Services but it was in front of the computer :(

We found a hidden redirect configuration that we missed.